# Is it better to schedule a python script via Task Scheduler or with code to run when needed?

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

So this is something I have been wondering for a while, and while I don't know if there is a correct answer there is probably a better option.

So which of the options below is best to schedule a python script to run at a specific time? Let me know what you prefer, or if you have an alternative.

1) Take a python file script.py, write a ".bat" file to run the code in command prompt, and then use windows native task scheduler to launch the file at a specific time each day.

BAT Example:

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Scripts
python script.py
```

This is some code for a BAT file that will run your python script.

2) Use python to create a timed task within your file like some of the examples below:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def hello_world():
    print "hello world"
    #...

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()
```

or

```
from datetime import date
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

# Define the function that is to be executed
def my_job(text):
    print text

# The job will be executed on November 6th, 2009
exec_date = date(2009, 11, 6)

# Store the job in a variable in case we want to cancel it
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, exec_date, ['text'])

# The job will be executed on November 6th, 2009 at 16:30:05
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, datetime(2009, 11, 6, 16, 30, 5), ['text'])
```

When it comes to option 2 there are plenty of examples I could include but I just want to know whats better in your opinion.

Does one of the options use more processing power? Is one of the options more reliable? etc.

Comment: Option 1 is very robust. Option 2 only works if you can guarantee that your process will live forever, which usually means babysitting it.

Comment: You can try watchdog as well

Answer (score 2):

I will choose option 1. If you choose option 2, your code will not run in several circumstances, such as your machine restart or your python IDE crashes.
Option 1 will run your code as long as your machine is running.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I do want to see if there are other answers before I select one but this was a good answer so I voted it up!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Option 2 personally.
In general, if you just have one or two servers. Task Scheduler (Windows) or cron (Linux) would be the way to go.

There are also tools like [AutoSys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Workload_Automation_AE) that are built for scheduling batch jobs.